# JQUERY move background with mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with class `box1` and it has following css properties(I've given a background image of a random pic from the web)

```
.box1{
  height:600px;
  width:600px;
  position:absolute;
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:150%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-image:url(http://www.slx-photographic.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Photography-Camera-HD-Wallpaper1.jpg);
}
```

The question is **HOW DO I MOVE THE BACKGROUND with movement of mouse using `mousemove();` method of jquery?** as of now I've come this far with JQUERY  and I can't seem to get it to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      var x = e.pageX;
      var y = e.pageY;

        $(".box1").css({
           ' background-position':'  x/2 +"20px" , y/2 + "20px" '
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to change the background position related to movement of mouse so it will be helpful if somebody could explain it if this is not how you do it..

Comment: `'background-position': Math.floor(x/2 + 20) + 'px  ' + Math.floor(y/2 + 20) + 'px'`

Comment: okay this is okay but its not moving the entire image to left or right , i'm trying to achive a parallax effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the quotes in jquery css method incorrectly. It should be like:

```
$(".box1").css({
  "background-position": x/2 + "20px ," +  y/2 + "20px"
});
```

Also you'd need to callibrate your `x` and `y` to distances from left of `box1` and top `box1` repectively. You could subract `box1`'s positions. This might be what you want: https://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/rEDIC