# Moving Backgrounds With Mouse Position ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am doing an ecommerce using react and redux. I would like to know how I could make the photo of the product when clicked receive zoom and could be controlled by the mouse. Like [this](https://www.adidas.com.br/tenis-easy-vulc-2.0/DB0002.html)

I found this  [article](https://css-tricks.com/moving-backgrounds-with-mouse-position/) and I tried to make the third example but I am not able to put it in my code.

This is the code of my Modal.js and the style.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Container, Image } from './styles';

export default class Modal extends Component {
  onClose = e => {
    this.props.onClose && this.props.onClose(e);
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Container>
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.onClose}>
          close
        </button>
        <Image>
          <div> /*This is <img src={image}/>*/{this.props.children}</div>
        </Image>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
Modal.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  show: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

Styles.js

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

  > button {
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #7159c1;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
`;
export const Image = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background: #ebedee;

  img {
    position: fixed;
    transform: scale(1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0;
    transition: background-position 0.25s;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQUERY move background with mouse movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316398/jquery-move-background-with-mouse-movement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any limitation that you cannot use any existing libraries? because i can recommend you this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-magnify).